# Targetting specific PHP minor version in Azure App Services

Tags: php, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I tried targeting a specific minor version of PHP in my YAML file and it crashed my pipeline.

I previously had `8.1` and attempted `8.1.10` (to match our current development environments). Without this, the app service seems to deploy `8.1.12`.

However, it seems that `composer` was finding `8.2` and failed to update based on this as my requirements in `composer.json` were `8.1`.

The App Service, in Azure, is configured for `8.1`.

Current code:

```
variables:
    phpVersion: '8.1'
```

Attempted:

```
variables:
    phpVersion: '8.1.10'
```

**Edit #1**

Pipeline info:

```
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-20.04
Agent: Hosted Agent
```

Comment: I'm not sure if setting a minor version is actually supported, setting 8.1.10 will use latest 8.1 i think, for me in the gui it only propose 8.0 and 8.1, and i don't think setting a different version with the yaml actually works.

Comment: Are you using self-host agent or MS-host agent?

Comment: Sorry, but how would I be able to tell? Somewhere in my pipeline?

Comment: You could check the pipeline running records `jobs`. [MS-host agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) do not have phpVersion '8.1.10' installed.

Comment: See Edit #1, is this the info your were referring to?

Comment: [Use a specific PHP version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/php?view=azure-devops#use-a-specific-php-version) may help.